# how to test static functions of C using google test

Tags: c, googletest, static-functions

I have a C file contains some static functions, how to use google test to test those static function?

header file:

```
test.h
int accessData();
```

source file:

```
test.c
static int value;
static int getData()
{
   return value;
}

int accessData()
{
    if(value != 0)
    {
       return getData();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

static function is called by global function, but how to test those static function using google test?

Comment: `#include` the source file instead of the header file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to `#include` the C source file into your test source (if it's using only the subset of C that's valid C++).  Then, the `static` function is part of the same translation unit as the test code, and can be called from it:

```
#include "test.c"

/* here follow the tests of getData() */
```

The downside to this is that everything in `test.c` gets compiled again, with obvious impact on build times.  If that gets to be a problem, you might consider extracting the static functions to be tested into their own source file (e.g. `test_p.c`, with the `_p` meaning private/internal).  Then `#include "test_p.c"` from both `test.c` and your unit test.

Comment: Additional problem with this is that Google Test compiles tests as C++. Some C code does not compile as C++. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: Agreed @user7610.  It's usually not hard to create C code that also compiles as C++ with the same semantics; I've added a parenthetical remark to ensure that's considered.

Comment: I remember fighting with designated initializers, recently. This is a C99 feature that only got into C++ in C++20.

Answer (score 6):

I understand that to test a function with google test, it must be visible to the test code. A static function is only visible to the current compilation unit.

A way to get around this is to "remove" the static attribute for test purposes:

```
#ifndef GOOGLE_TEST
# define STATIC static
#else
# define STATIC
#endif

STATIC int getData();
```

If this gives conflicts, for example because there aer `getData()` functions in many source files, you could create simple container functions:

```
static int getData(<arglist>);

#ifdef GOOGLE_TEST
int myModule_getData(<arglist>) {return(getData(<arglist>);}
...
#endif
```

Comment: Conflicts should be unlikely if your tests exercise only one implementation file per test suite.  I'd certainly advocate that as the preferable option, with the wrapper functions being the last resort.

Answer (score -1):

A `static` function has it's visibility limited to the translation unit.

AFAIK,  for googletest, you need to call the function(s) under test from a separate test file conating the test code written with `TEST()`. If the function under test is `static`, simply it is not possible to test that directly from the `TEST()` MACRO invocation.

The straightway approach is to, comment out the `static` modifier for the function for testing purpose.

Comment: Considering that usual projects have tens if not even hundrets or thousands of compilation units, commenting out the `static` keyword isn't a very pratical approach.